# Time ago in words i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there way to get [time_ago_in_words](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words) in different languages, or write locales?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s my investigation:

time_ago_in_words calls distance_of_time_in_words (https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words)
The api docs for that method mention translations in the scope of datetime.distance_in_words.
If you look for distance_in_words in a default locale, such as this en.yml (https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml) you’ll see all the available translations in that space. You can redefine any of these in your locale file.

If, however, you’re just trying to change the language it uses, it seems I18n contains a great many default locales, you need to set the locale either as a default within your app, or from the locale defined in the browser.

To set the default for the app, you’ll need a line like this in config/application.rb

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :de
```

You can see the list of default locales here (use the part before .yml) https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the rails i18 locale file en.yml https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml and can use their predefined translations. If you want to change the translations you can also override the en.yml file in your repository.